# How to assign regex from sharepoint list to javascript variable?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, regex, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

In visual webpart am trying to assign the regularexpression from sharepoint list to hiddenvariable at server side and then 
accessing at client side. But its not working

Below is my sample code, which is not working

```
var iChars = $("#<=hdnSplChar.ClientID%>").val();
iChars.test(fileName)
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSplChar" runat="server" />
```

Below is the sample code, is working

```
var iChars = /^[ A-Za-z0-9_(.)%]*$/ 
iChars.test(fileName)
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSplChar" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var iChars = $('#'+<%=hdnSplChar.ClientID%>);
```

Comment: after dynamically assign the regex expression to hidden variable, am able to access at client side. But that regex expression is not working at client side.

Comment: Your answer has appeared in the low quality posts. Please attach an explanation as to how this solves the OPs problem.